# Java set of byte arrays

Tags: java, set

I have a HashSet of `byte[]`s and I would like to test whether a new `byte[]` is in that set.  The problem is that Java seems to be testing whether the `byte[]` instances are the same rather than testing whether the actual values in the byte arrays are the same.

In other words, consider the following code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.util.HashSet<byte[]> set=new java.util.HashSet<byte[]>();
        set.add(new String("abc").getBytes());
        System.out.println(set.contains(new String("abc").getBytes()));
    }
}
```

This code prints out `false` and I would like it to print out `true`.  How should I go about doing this?

Comment: In all these answers, be wary of changing any elements of a byte array that is in the set; doing so will affect its hash and it's equality, but will not change the hash-bucket it's currently stored in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a set of array in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841934/how-to-make-a-set-of-array-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap each byte array using `ByteBuffer.wrap`, which will provide the right equals and hashCode behavior for you. Just be careful what methods you call on the `ByteBuffer` (that you don't modify the array or advance its pointer).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `ByteArray` class that wraps the byte arrays and tests for equality the way you want.  Then you'd have a `Set<ByteArray>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own wrapper class, but probably the easiest thing to do is to "wrap" the arrays into ArrayLists and use a `HashSet<ArrayList>`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modern ( as of right now solution )

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Set;

import static com.google.common.base.Charsets.UTF_8;
import static java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap;

public class Scratch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Set<ByteBuffer> bbs = ImmutableSet.of(wrap("abc".getBytes(UTF_8)).asReadOnlyBuffer());
        System.out.println("bbs.contains(ByteBuffer.wrap(\"abc\".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8))) = " + bbs.contains(wrap("abc".getBytes(UTF_8)).asReadOnlyBuffer()));
    }
}
```

#### NOTES:

You should **never** convert a `String` to a `byte[]` without providing a `Charset` the results become runtime dependant based on the default `Charset` which is usually not a good one and can change.

`.asReadOnlyBuffer()` is important!

> Creates a new, read-only byte buffer that shares this buffer's
>   content. The content of the new buffer will be that of this buffer.
>   Changes to this buffer's content will be visible in the new buffer;
>   the new buffer itself, however, will be read-only and will not allow
>   the shared content to be modified.
>
> The two buffers' position, limit, and mark values will be independent.
>
> The new buffer's capacity, limit, position, and mark values will be identical to those of this buffer.
>   If this buffer is itself read-only then this method behaves in exactly
>   the same way as the duplicate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid wrappers and the stupid hashCode problem (hey, a standard thing like a byte[] doesn't have hashCode right?):

Use TreeSet instead of HashSet and provide a byte[] comparator at instantiation time:

```
  Set<byte[]> byteATreeSet = new TreeSet<byte[]>(new Comparator<byte[]>() {
    public int compare(byte[] left, byte[] right) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < left.length && j < right.length; i++, j++) {
        int a = (left[i] & 0xff);
        int b = (right[j] & 0xff);
        if (a != b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
    return left.length - right.length;
   }});
```

If you get a byte[] HashSet b from somewhere else, initialize your variable a before as TreeSet and then use a.addAll(b); This way, even if b contained duplicates, a does not.

Comment: Worth noting that TreeSet has worse time complexity for add, remove, contains methods than HashSet (O(lg n) vs O(1)), which might be an important factor.