# How to make a set of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, set

Since the equals function in array only check the instance, it doesn't work well with Set.
Hence, I wonder how to make a set of arrays in Java?

One possible way could be put each array in an object, and implement equals function for that class, but will that decrease the performance too much?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since the ArrayList class already wraps an array, you can extend it and override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Here is a sample:

```
public MyArrayList extends ArrayList<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof MyArrayList) {
            //place your comparison logic here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //just a sample, you can place your own code
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

You can even override it for a generic use, just changing the code to:

```
public MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    //overrides the methods you need
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof MyArrayList) {
            //place your comparison logic here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use raw Arrays unless you absolutely have to because of some legacy API that requires an Array.

Always try and use a type safe `ArrayList<T>` instead and you won't have these kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your Set be an instance of TreeSet, you can specify a custom Comparator which will be used for all comparisons (even equality).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class for your array and override hashcode and equals accordingly.
For example:

```java
public class MyArrayContainer {
    int[] myArray = new int[100];

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (null != other && other instanceof MyArrayContainer) {
            MyArrayContainer o = (MyArrayContainer) other;
            final int myLength = myArray.length;
            if (o.myArray.length != myLength) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
                if (myArray[i] != o.myArray[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return myArray.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 9*, you can use [`Arrays::compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-T:A-T:A-) method as a comparator for `TreeSet` that compares the *contents* of arrays.

```java
Set<String[]> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare);

String[] val1 = {"one", "two"};
String[] val2 = {"one", "two"};
String[] val3 = {"one", "two"};

set.add(val1);
set.add(val2);

System.out.println(set.size()); // 1
System.out.println(set.contains(val1)); // true
System.out.println(set.contains(val2)); // true
System.out.println(set.contains(val3)); // true
```

---

<sup>See also: [Check if an array exists in a `HashSet<int[]>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65463604/16119950)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use lists for this problem.
Also, use trusted sources to ensure that [Java is properly configured](https://gelxy.com/u/13) on your system; Read the complete information in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: The website linked does have an English-version page

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31525211)

Answer (score -3):

A class that extends Set and override the equals method could do it.