# Duplicate int[] added in a hashset?

Tags: java, int, duplicates, addition, hashset

I juste learned JAVA and I have a problem with this code :

```
HashSet myHashSet = new HashSet();

int[] tab1 = new int[] {0,0};
int[] tab2 = new int[] {0,0};

myHashSet.add(tab1);
myHashSet.add(tab2);
```

Now my `HashSet` contains `{{0;0};{0;0}}`! How can I manage simply to not have duplicates in this case?
I thought `HashSet` didn't allow duplicates.

Comment: Arrays in Java do not have an equality-useful `hashCode` or `equals`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657905/hashset-of-array-of-int-hashsetint-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet` doesn't allow duplicated based on `hashCode` and `equals` methods, but arrays don't override such methods, so even if you have two arrays with the same content, they **are not** the *same* arrays, so they will be allowed in a `Set`.

Use `List<Integer>` instead. Note the usage of `Integer` over `int` because generics don't support primitive types.

Comment: Another, more efficient option is to wrap each `int` array in an [IntBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Two arrays, even if they contain the same elements, may not be equal, because equality is defined as reference-equality for non-primitives.